# Билет в транспорте компоссируют или компостируют?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Скажите, пожалуйста, а билет в транспорте компоссируют или компостируют?

Спасибо.

Comment: В многотомном Б&Э слова компостер нет, впервые в Словаре иностранных слов Чудинова (1910), объясняется как типографский термин "наборная верстать"(?)
> Исторический словарь галлицизмов русского языка 
КОМПОСТЕР а, м. composteur m.. нем. Komposter. 1. Прибор в виде щипцов, пробивающий или выдавливающий условные знаки контроля (на пломбах, билетах и т. п.). Уш. 1934. БАС-1. нем. kompostieren. Компостирование я, ср. Процесс пробивания дырочек в билет при помощи компостера называется компостированием (**не компосированием**). 
В франц. composter (компостировать) согласная **t** произносится.

Answer (score 3):

С помощью компо**ст**ера билет компо**ст**ируют. Последний раз компостером мне доводилось пользоваться лет 15 назад, правда люди, компостирующие мозги, от этого не перевелись.

[Ожегов, Шведова](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/87214)

Comment: Троллейбусы по-прежнему с компостерами :)

Comment: Где это? У нас - наличка и электронные проездные. И машинки соответствующие у кондукторов. Кстати, как они называются?

Comment: >И машинки соответствующие у кондукторов. Кстати, как они называются?  
  
А это это смотря чему они "соответствующие". Устройство, проверяющее подлинность и действительность электронной или магнитной карты (всякого вида и назначения), называется валидатором. Такие обычно стоят в метро и у контролеров, хотя сейчас они тоже комюинированные. А если у устройства есть еще какие-то функции, то *возможны варианты*.

Comment: Для @Docentl. В Киеве и не только. 
 

Сейчас "знакомлюсь" с московскими проездными. Оказалось, что в автобусе нельзя взять билет на 1 поездку, только на 2. Загадкой для меня пока остается проездной "90 минут".

Comment: Валидатор - похоже. Он еще снимает деньги с транспортной карты. А льготную просто проверяет - зачислены ли деньги.

Comment: Тогда и говорите "валидатор". По основной функции. Съем денег - это уже процессинговая функция, в банковских автоматах у неё есть како-то специальное название, не вспомню сейчас, но само действие тут вторично.

Comment: > тогда и говорите "валидатор"  

Буду. Осталось найти - кому? :-)

Comment: У нас в Симферополе тоже все троллейбуса с компостерами, как в старые добрые времена (при этом они же с телевизорами и даже местами с вайфаем)))).

Comment: Как Вы лихо завернули : *все троллейбусА*! Зачот))) 
Кстати, стоимость билетов в транспорте некоторым категориям пассажиров - **компенсируют**.
>А компот? - Налейте ему компот...

Answer (score 1):

> правда люди компостирующие мозги от этого не перевелись

Надо бы поправить положение с запятыми.

Answer (score -1):

Компостируют, конечно. Слово "компоссировать" в русском языке нет.
Но если смотреть на вопрос шире, то не все так просто.

Надо бы точно посмотреть, откуда пришло слово в этом значении: "*гасить* билет методом пробивания отверстий или проставления специальной отметки".
Точно могу сказать, что оно берет начало с железных дорог позапрошлого столетия. Именно так - и только так погашали первые бумажные или картонные билеты. До того билеты были металлическими жетонами - и подлежали не гашению, а возврату проводнику.
Навскидку, в английском подобного значения нет, compost, composting - прежде всего утилизация разного рода отходов. Видимо это значение "утилизация" и стало в русском синонимом пробивания.
Но если подобное слово есть во французском - а по внешним признакам похоже, - то вариант "компоссирование" по крайней мере объясним. 
Это все в порядке бреда, серьёзно разбираться сейчас просто нет возможности.

Ну поскольку никакого "компоста" (типа "compost" - c непроизносимыми s и t) со значением пробивать дырки фо французском так и не обнаружено (несмотря на все усилия отдельных форумян доказать обратное), полагаю, что "компос(с)ировать" действительно не может быть объяснимо захватом французского слова.

> Пардон, я забыл, что на сайте есть тормоза. Composter (фр.) - компостировать. Правду люди говорят)))

(grumant)

Да, я тоже забыл было, простите. Но теперь буду знать и повторять по три раза (чего обычно не делаю, ибо считаю двух достаточным): "Ну поскольку никакого "компоста" (типа "compost" - c непроизносимыми s и t)..." (далее по тексту).

Comment: > Видимо это значение "утилизация" и стало в русском синонимом пробивания.

Действительно бред, сочинять версию на основе явно недостаточных сведений, имея возможность все эти факты проверить в течении минуты.

 "Компост", как и "композиты", произошёл от латинского корня compositus, составной. В русском слово тоже наличествует с тем же значением, что и в английском ( удобрение из **смеси** разнообразных веществ растительного, животного и минерального происхождения) и прокомпостированный билет - явно не компост.

Компостер от com+postus - сопомещение. Слово действительно есть во французском.

Comment: >Действительно бред, сочинять версию на основе явно недостаточных сведений    
  
Где вы увимдели "версию" уважаемый? Я рассуждал. 
А уж нести ахиненею про происхождение от чего-то там латинского - это просто ниже всякой критики.  В русском почтити нет прямых латинских заимствований, все попали либо через французский, либо через немецкий. Реже - английский.
А уж рассказывать человеку, полжизни этот компост на своём участке разбрасывающему, что слово есть в русском, - это уже верх самомнения.
На вопрос вы так и не ответили. Есть ли слово со *сходным* значением...

Comment: Есть во французском слово сomposteur, о чём упоминают почти все словари. В современном французском перфорирование билета для компостера уже не обязательно и валидаторы называть компостером тоже допустимо.

Естественно заимствование было и в том и другом случае непрямым, но в обоих случаях установить от кого заимствовано конкретно, установить вряд ли возможно. Компостером пользовались и немцы, и французы, компостом - ещё и англичане.

А причину усомниться в понимании вами термина компост, я процитировал выше. Один бумажный билет "смесью" быть ну никак не может.

Comment: >>Есть во французском слово сomposteur, о чём упоминают почти все словари  
  
Мне уже порядком надоедает вести этот спор ни о чем, нот последняя попытка.
Значение "перфорировать" есть во французском или "допустимо"?  

ЗЫ У меня нет французских словарей. И я не столь самонадеян, чтобы доверяться ощущением, не зная толком языка. *Не в пример Вам, кстати.* 
Что же касается "компоста" и "причины сомневаться", Вы простите, опять несете ахинею. Не решайте за других, ага? **Я не сомневаюсь в значении  слова "коспост".** Ни секунды. Я его просто знаю.

Comment: Простите, мне всегда казалось, что значение отдельного слова в начальной форме найти с помощью словаря можно в любом языке, независимо от степени владения им. Французско-русских словарей в интернете море, например [этот](http://slovari.yandex.ru/composteur/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/#lingvo/) или [этот](http://slovarionline.ru/bolshoy_frantsuzsko_russkiy_i_russko_frantsuzskiy_slovar/search/?word=composteur&select=bolshoy_frantsuzsko_russkiy_i_russko_frantsuzskiy_slovar&sub.x=16&sub.y=17). Главное для "composteur" изменить каким-либо образом билет, в том числе и перфорировать.

Comment: > У меня нет французских словарей.

@behemothus Они всегда есть в Сети.

Comment: Не для таких целей. 
Простите, но отслеживать тонкое различие значений по словарным статьям из неизвестно кем оцифрованных инет-словарей - это не для "благородных донов".

Самое любопытное, что четкого ответа так и не поступило. Вопрос был: Есть ли во французском такое слово с нужным значением. Вместо этого начался по выражению уважаемого 'Марк Из' "толстый троллинг".